# Method call gives inconsistent result for same arguments

Tags: java, java-native-interface, libsodium

I get inconsistent results for the blake2b hash, which is a functional method. The issue - as it looks to me - is on the java side that somehow performs changes on the input arguments between the two method calls. I can't understand what is going on with the input arguments between the two calls to `SodiumJNI.crypto_generichash_blake2b_salt_personal_no_input`. The native function (as shown below) does not perform any changes on `key`, `salt`, and `info`. The output should therefore be identical, but it isn't.

My test method looks as follows:

```
 import android.util.Base64;
 import android.util.Log;

 static void kdf() {
        final byte[] key = new byte[32];
        final byte[] salt = new byte[32];
        final byte[] info = Base64.decode("aGFuZHNoYWtl", Base64.DEFAULT);

        byte[] out0 = new byte[64];
        int result0 = SodiumJNI.crypto_generichash_blake2b_salt_personal_no_input(out0, out0.length, key, key.length, salt, info);
        if (result0 == 0) {
            Log.d("Tests", "out0: " + Base64.encodeToString(out0, Base64.DEFAULT));
            //prints:
            //out0: nCzeDcbw1YmdPq+jYnslNDoXKNyXMvIsqx9QJ1PLRNPxh7dvXkTeSkF2REYznHExaWCQP7J0kFvDu9l9ECs4VQ==
        }

        byte[] out1 = new byte[64];
        int result1 = SodiumJNI.crypto_generichash_blake2b_salt_personal_no_input(out1, out1.length, key, key.length, salt, info);
        if (result1 == 0) {
            Log.d("Tests", "out1: " + Base64.encodeToString(out1, Base64.DEFAULT));
             //prints;
             //out1: dNfj+ccfGzTDiTAgzHNE5Hujyxnl6yX2BAPamCBw8X3fPYgbdtNDPoA3JKQGCziJw40wVTr/kPCpVUqMqMiVKw==
        }
    }
```

Now strangely enough `out0` and `out1` are not identical.

The native function implementation looks like this:

```
public class SodiumJNI {

    public final static native int sodium_init();
    public final static native int crypto_generichash_blake2b_salt_personal_no_input(byte[] out, int outlen, byte [] key, int keylen, byte[] salt, byte[] personal);

    static {
        try {
            System.loadLibrary("sodiumjni");
            if (sodium_init() == -1) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Sodium could not be initialized.");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);


        }
    }
}
```

And the native function:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_app_jni_SodiumJNI_crypto_1generichash_1blake2b_1salt_1personal_1no_1input(JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jcls,
  jbyteArray joutput, jint joutlength, jbyteArray jkey, jint jkeylength, jbyteArray jsalt, jbyteArray jpersonal) {
  jint jresult = 0 ;
  unsigned char *output = (unsigned char *) 0 ;
  size_t outlength ;
  unsigned char *key = (unsigned char *) 0 ;
  size_t keylength ;
  unsigned char *salt = (unsigned char *) 0 ;
  unsigned char *personal = (unsigned char *) 0 ;
  int result;

  (void)jenv;
  (void)jcls;
  {
    output = (unsigned char *) (*jenv)->GetByteArrayElements(jenv, joutput, 0);
  }
  outlength = (size_t)joutlength;
  {
    key = (unsigned char *) (*jenv)->GetByteArrayElements(jenv, jkey, 0);
  }
  keylength = (size_t)jkeylength;
  {
    salt = (unsigned char *) (*jenv)->GetByteArrayElements(jenv, jsalt, 0);
  }
  {
    personal = (unsigned char *) (*jenv)->GetByteArrayElements(jenv, jpersonal, 0);
  }

  result = (int)crypto_generichash_blake2b_salt_personal(output,
      outlength,
      NULL,
      0,
      (unsigned char const *)key,
      keylength,
      (unsigned char const *)salt,
      (unsigned char const *)personal);
  jresult = (jint)result;
  {
    (*jenv)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(jenv, joutput, (jbyte *) output, 0);
  }
  {
    (*jenv)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(jenv, jkey, (jbyte *) key, JNI_ABORT);
  }
  {
    (*jenv)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(jenv, jsalt, (jbyte *) salt, JNI_ABORT);
  }
  {
    (*jenv)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(jenv, jpersonal, (jbyte *) personal, JNI_ABORT);
  }
  return jresult;
}
```

Comment: Well... out0 and out1 point to different memory locations. So you'd get different results.

Comment: The log does not print the location but the content.

Comment: `GetByteArrayElements` _can_ return a copy, but is not _guaranteed_ to return a copy. It may well return a pointer to the actual data.

Comment: Please elaborate. Do you see the issue where the c arrays get released, where they get instantiated, or where they get passed to the libsodium blake2b method?

Comment: My point is that you seem to assume that `GetByteArrayElements` returns a copy to the data, that you can modify without altering the corresponding Java array. However, there's no guarantee that what you got was a copy, so you may have to create the copy yourself. The last argument to `GetByteArrayElements` can be used to determine this (i.e. `jboolean *isCopy`).

Comment: I thought that releasing the array with mode 0 (as done here:
(*jenv)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(jenv, joutput, (jbyte *) output, 0); ) would make sure that the data is copied back to the jarray in case of a copy.  The documentation seems to support this.

Comment: Right, but that's the opposite scenario you're talking about. I'm talking about the scenario where you're inadvertedly modifying a Java array when you think that you're modifying a copy.

Comment: Wouldn't that be desirable as I want the output array to be modified. For the other arrays I release them with JNI_ABORD that makes sure that no modifications are made. Also they are passed as const to the blake2b method.

Comment: The `mode` parameter (`JNI_ABORT`) has no effect unless `GetByteArrayElements` returned a copy. And like I've been saying since my first comment, there's no guarantee that `GetByteArrayElements` will return a copy. The fact that you cast to `const*` doesn't really mean anything, since we don't know what `crypto_generichash_blake2b_salt_personal` does with those pointers (you haven't shown us that code).